# Novel with trainee herald - Tasting the blood of your first kill prevents haunting

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a book I read years ago but can't remember the name of the author or book title

I can only remember bits out of the book:

The two main characters are traveling - they are guys and they end up together one has an unusual name, a herald in training I think. There was an ambush and people were killed with swords, bow and arrows and they have to taste the blood of the first person they killed or he will haunt them their entire life. Also, there are these cabin/houses that have different lights - the main guy asked what they meant and someone said if you dont know what they mean then you're too young to know.

Comment: How many years ago? Do you remember anything else about the heroes (ages, special characteristics, etc)? Was there literal haunting by ghosts?

Comment: i read it about 10-12 years ago and its older then that so im guessing it came out in the 90's somewhere. no actual haunting of ghost i think its just something people said. i think one of the main characters is 15-16 his name is darrien, darren or alec i cant fully remember the other one is a bit older. i also remember the older main character use to be in love with his best friend. i only remember bits and pieces of it which makes it hard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are describing and searching is the [Nightrunner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nightrunner_Series) series from Lynn Flewelling.

[image]

I don`t have the books right here, but one of the key points I remember is that the sexuality in this series is relatively free, so there are brothels in different colored lights for all the pairings of M/M, M/F, F/M, F/F.

"If you don't know what they mean, then you're too young to know." That's the answer, the younger protagonist, Alec, receives when he sees the older Seregil walking into one of the brothels.

Also, the Alec is forced by either Seregil or Micum (a friend of Seregil) to drink the blood from the arrow of his first victim.

I`m looking for more information to add to this, as soon as I get home.

Comment: What does the M/F, F/M dictate?

Comment: @Dreamwalker:
Male/Female, Female/Male. Presumably, unless one is indicating dominance (a surprisingly common trend in some story communities) or specific non-parallel sex activities, they're the same thing.

Comment: @SeanDuggan well I did think dominance as well I've just not come across this before in any books.

Comment: @Dreamwalker:
Honestly, it's just as likely that the person writing this was just trying to be comprehensive and added a bit of redundancy. :) I've personally never read the books in question.

Comment: @Dreamwalker: Sorry, I should have added. M/F means e.g. male prostitute/ female customer, F/M means female prostitute/ male customer.

Comment: Wow, so I don't know if you answered OP's question, but I was obsessively trying to remember that exact scene from that exact book that I read like 12 years ago, and am shocked I actually found it and it's all thanks to this post so THANK YOU!